# To run a python script existing on a remote machine using ssh and fab using another python program

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, remote-access, fabric

I tried

```
from fabric.api import *
print "Hello"
def deploy():
    with settings(hosts_string="remote", user = "student", key_filename="~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"):
    print "KKKKK"
    put('/media/saranubuntu/6CD4FB2CD4FAF6E4/sum0/exper/sumoStats-master/', '/home/student/exper/New')
    run('python /home/student/exper/New/sumoStats-master/runEmall.py')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   deploy()
```

it is showing an error like

Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 2 while executing!

Requested: python /home/student/exper/New/sumoStats-master/runEmall.py
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "python /home/student/exper/New/sumoStats-master/runEmall.py"

Aborting.
run() received nonzero return code 2 while executing!

Requested: python /home/student/exper/New/sumoStats-master/runEmall.py
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "python /home/student/exper/New/sumoStats-master/runEmall.py"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like error occurred while trying execute
`/home/student/exper/New/sumoStats-master/runEmall.py`

You can try to run

`run('python /home/student/exper/New/sumoStats-master/runEmall.py', stderr=sys.stdout)`

To get possible errors from STDERR, or try to run in manually from "remote" computer to see why exactly did it fails.